# I wrote this code for selection sort, but it is doing nothing

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>


void swap(int a[60],int p, int min){
  int temp;
  if (min!=p){
    temp= a[p];
    a[p]=a[min];
    a[min]=temp;
  }
  return;
}

void selection(int a[60]){
  int p=0;
  do {
    int min = p;
    for ( int i=p+1;i<60;i++){
      if(a[min]>a[p])min=p;

    }
    swap(a,p,min);
    p++;
  } while(p<60);
}




int main(){
    int a[60];
    int p=0;
    while(p<60){
      scanf("%d\n",&a[p]);
      p++;
    }
    selection(a);
    p=0;
    while(p<60){
      printf("%d\n",a[p]);
      p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. In the main the first function scans a 60 sized array from the standard input.
2. A selection function defined above is called which 'should' sort the array
3. The selection function defines a variable p to be able to go through the array 60 times
4. Another for loop finds the lowest element in the array
5. If found, the swap function swaps the array values in the minimum and p position
6. The loop runs 60 times to sort the array
7. Print array is called in main function

Comment: Your `if(a[min]>a[p])min=p;` is causing the problem. `p` doesn't change. `i` does.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, take the tour to learn what questions to ask and how. Here there is no question.

Comment: Thanks @MayankVerma.

Comment: @JensGustedt Hello, Thank you, I'll keep this in mind. Can you point me to links where I can see how C(C++) is uncontested in domain. 
Say, I want to become someone like you, a researcher
Some things I could bookmark! ... .. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
for ( int i=p+1;i<60;i++){
  if(a[min]>a[p])min=p;
}
```

Your loop is comparing `a[min]` with `a[p]` to see which is smaller.  `p` isn't changing in the loop however, `i` is.  That's the index you need to compare with and set `min` to if you find a smaller number:

```
  if(a[min]>a[i]) min=i;
```

Comment: Thanks, what a naive mistake :)